# I want to write an iOS app and run it strictly for my own use on my own phone. Possible?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

To be very clear: I have a free Apple Developer account. I am running Xcode [Version 6.1 (6A1046a)] on a MacBook Pro / OSX [Version 10.10.3 (14D136)] I have Apple Configurator [Version 1.7.2 (560)] Is it possible for me to develop an app, upload it to just my iPhone 6 without paying $100 to Apple? I do not want to jailbreak the phone. I do not want to submit or sell the app in the Apple Store. I do not want the app to run on any other phones. If so ... pointers to somewhere describing the process. PLEASE no links to "Here's how you submit a app to the Apple Store." ... not what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible **(ONLY WITH PAID ACCOUNT)**

Im curious if you can send the source code to someone who has a paid account and they could build it for you. I think that is the only way this would work with a free account.

** I would recommend spending the 100$ to get the developer account, then you can follow these steps **

All your going to want to do is

1. plug your phone into your Mac
2. Open xCode / your project your trying to build to phone
3. where you normally select your device for iOS simulator, select your iphone (should be at top of list)

[image]

4. [command + R] will build it to that device
5. hit stop button
6. unplug iphone and enjoy

Comment: This is only possible using the paid Apple Developer account. Free accounts are limited to simulator only.

Comment: ah, thanks for the heads-up drew. I did not know they limited the free account

Comment: In 2024, must be paid account with latest macos. Better hope Sonoma doesn't break your  stuff (it will if it's open source), better hope your iPhone doesn't update again stopping you uploading any more. Apple have made these phones into dumb consoles.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE (6/9/15): Starting with Xcode 7, developer program membership is not required to run an app on your device.

No. You must be a part of the paid Apple Developer program in order to put any app you've developed on any iOS device, whether via the App Store, ad hoc distribution, or even by connecting your device to your Xcode project. Free accounts are limited to running in the simulator.